# Not getting the specific output without braces

Tags: php, echo, quote

please explain me why am I not getting the whole output with the following line:

```
echo"$x+$y=".$x+$y."</br>";
```

I were only getting the print of the addition without the string getting printed. But the output is perfect with this statement:

```
echo"$x+$y=".($x+$y)."</br>";
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: For the first statement the output is 17(if $x=10 and $y=7), without the string before. For the second statement its 10+7=17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) 101. The `+` and `.` operators have the same precedence and left-to-right associativity, so without braces the operations are evaluated from left to right.

Consider this example which I've adapted from your question's code:

```
$x = 3;
$y = 5;
echo "$x+$y=" . $x + $y;
```

Variable names inside double quotes will be expanded (a.k.a. string interpolation) so it is evaluated as follows:

```
echo "3+5=" . 3 + 5;
echo ("3+5=" . 3) + 5; //added braces to demonstrate actual operations order
echo "3+5=3" + 5;
echo 3 + 5; //string evaluated in numeric context is coerced to number¹
echo 8;
```

In the question's original code there's one more string concatenation which will concatenate this result with another string and that's it.

¹ From [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

And of course, you can always use braces to force operations' precedence in order to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm confused. $x=3;$y=5;echo "$x+$y=".$x+0; //Returns 3. Looks like it does the + first in this case.

Comment: @Sanchit mhm that's an interesting case. There's string interpolation involved there, I'll update the answer once I solve it.

Comment: Ok I understood about the precedence. But why "=" is not getting printed? Is the execution stopped after the addition?

Comment: @techani the whole string is coerced to a number once it reaches the arithmetic sum operation.

Comment: @Sanchit I adapted your example a bit to reflect OP's code (replaced your `0` by `$y`) and added the expression evaluation to the answer. `=]`

Comment: @techani See the second example I've added, I believe it makes more sense now.

Comment: Cool thanks. PHP probably does intval("3+5=3") which is equal 3 which is what was happening. By the way intval("non-numeric string1") = 0. So your second explaination probably works for the first one as well. =] Just use parenthesis and avoid problems is the moral of this story I think.

Comment: @Sanchit Yes parentheses are the way to go. One thing though - PHP does not use intval for string to number conversion, it also accepts floats, hex and exponent notation. Guess I'll add that part to the answer as well.

Comment: As far as I understand, after this statement " echo "3+5=3" + 5; ", "=3" is left aside and only " 3+ 5 " is worked on. Is that right? Then why did php pull ".3" anyway inside the quote? Coz it had the "+" sign on which it had to work from the beginning. Please bear with me if I sound dumb here. Am just trying to clarify the concept to myself. Thank you.

Comment: @techani at `"3+5=3" + 3`, the string `"3+5=3"` becomes the number value `3`. This behavior is explained in the quoted text and there are examples in the link I've posted in the answer. The other `3` goes in `=3` because of the precedence order/associativity - the `"3+5=" . 3` concatenation executes first.

Comment: From what Fabricio quoted. PHP converts "3+5=3" into the number "3". It would convert "3+999=3", "3+99=2", "3.0+82+77" all into 3 as well. It just looks at the begining and tries to find numbers (decimals are cool too); stops when it finds something non numeric and returns whatever it has found so far.  What it does after is just addition. It adds the 3 to the value of $y (5) and hence returns 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the expression like this to see the sequence of evaluations: `((("$x+$y=".$x) + $y)."</br>");`

Here is what happens in detail:

1. The string is interpolated takes place changing `"$x+$y="` to `"10+7="`
2. The string concatenation takes place `"10+7=".$x` leading to `"10+7=10"`
3. The addition between a string and a number takes place `"10+7=10"+$y` evaluates to `"10+7"` and eventually `"17"` because php attempts to convert the string into a number. During this process it starts at the left side of the string and in your example it finds `10`. Next the `+` symbol is found, which is not a number and this terminates the attempt to convert the string into a number. However, what has been found to be a number (`10`) remains as the numeric interpretation of the string.
4. `17` is concatenated with the last string `<br>` and this is echoed out.

Hope that helps,
Loddi

Answer (score 0):

This is due to operator precedence for more details you can refer http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

For visible format you can use

```
echo '$x+$y='.($x+$y)."</br>";
```

output : $x+$y = 15